# ef linq join on nullable field

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join, nullable

C#(model + linq):

```
public class RepairRecord 
{
    public Guid? CheckId {get;set;}
    //more properties
}
public class ProductTracking
{
    public Guid? CheckId {get;set;}
    //more properties
}

var query = from a in context.Set<RepairRecord>()
                        join b in context.Set<ProductTracking>() on a.CheckId.Value equals b.CheckId.Value
                        select 1;

var queryResult = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Sql:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[MES_REPAIR_RECORD] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MES_PRODUCT_TRACKING] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[CHECK_ID] = [Extent2].[CHECK_ID]) OR (([Extent1].[CHECK_ID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent2].[CHECK_ID] IS NULL))
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

I do not need the null value match, How can I modify my C# to make the sql seems like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Limit1].[C1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT TOP (1) 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM  [dbo].[MES_REPAIR_RECORD] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[MES_PRODUCT_TRACKING] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent1].[CHECK_ID] = [Extent2].[CHECK_ID])
    )  AS [Limit1]
```

**the Definition of model in my scenerio can not be modified**

Comment: Make Check_ID not nullable.  If you are using it for a unique identifier it probably should not be nullable anyway.

Comment: In my scenerio, check_id is nullable and this is essential

Comment: Show the models, not the SQL

Comment: Please show us all models completely and explain what do you want to archive - expect a left join in EF by LINQ.